# Include another select column based on data - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I include `SUM((pm.Quantity * bl.TotalQty)) AS NextBOMItemCount WHERE projectbomlist.ParentPartNum = bl.PartNum`?

The data should not be changed, the same data should be retrieved, the however additional column has to be included.

VIEW: `NEWprojectBOMItemCount

```
select 
    `pm`.`ProjectCode` AS `ProjectCode`,
    `bl`.`PartNum` AS `PartNum`, 
    sum((`pm`.`Quantity` * `bl`.`TotalQty`)) AS `BOMItemCount`, 
    `bl`.`mp` AS `mp`, 
    `p`.`complete` AS `complete`, 
    `bl`.`RMInd` AS `RMInd`, 
    `bl`.`M_PartNum` AS `M_PartNum`
from 
    (
        (`projectmachine` `pm` join `projectbomlist` `bl`) 
        join `projects` `p`
    )
where 
    (
        (`pm`.`MachineListID` = `bl`.`MachineListID`)
        and (`pm`.`ProjectCode` = `bl`.`ProjectCode`)
        and (`pm`.`ProjectCode` = `p`.`ProjectCode`)
        and (`p`.`AfterProjectHeirarchyInd` = 'Y')
    )
    and and pm.ProjectCode = 'AB212323'
group by 
    `pm`.`ProjectCode` , 
    `bl`.`PartNum`
order by 
    `pm`.`ProjectCode` , 
    `bl`.`PartNum`
```

Or, another option can be, please consider above view used in below query, please suggest changes to the below query as shown above (repeating here)

```
`sum((pm.Quantity * bl.TotalQty)) AS NextBOMItemCount where projectbomlist.ParentPartNum = bl.PartNum` - in place of `(select-NextBOMItemCount)`?
```

Please see `PBLH.ParentPartNum` is the column that I should compare with `BL.ProjectCode` to get `NextBOMItemCount value`.

QUERY calling view: `NEWprojectBOMItemCount`

```
Select 
    BL.PartNum PartNumber, 
    PBLH.ParentPartNum NextBOM,  
    (select-NextBOMItemCount), 
    BOMItemCount TotalQty, 
    PL.Description, 
    BL.MP as PartType, 
    PL.Vendor, 
    PL.QBType  
from 
    NEWprojectBOMItemcount BL, 
    bomwiz.partslist PL, 
    bomwiz.projectbomlistheirarchy PBLH  
Where 
    BL.PartNum = PL.PartNum  
    And BL.PartNum = PBLH.PartNum  
    And BL.ProjectCode = PBLH.ProjectCode 
    And BL.projectCode = 'AB212323' 
Order By PartNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for *conditional aggregation*. Your requirement could be expressed as follows:

```
SUM(
    CASE WHEN blh.ParentPartNum = bl.PartNum 
        THEN pm.Quantity * bl.TotalQty 
        ELSE 0 
    END
) AS NextBOMItemCount
```

Let me pinpoint other issues with your query:

- you have unwanted parentheses all around, and I am suspicious about the syntax of the `JOIN`s ; you need to move conditions to the `ON` clause of the relevant `JOIN`.
- every non-aggregated column must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause - you have missing columns there
- backquotes are usually not needed

Here is an updated version of the query:

```
SELECT 
    pm.ProjectCode AS ProjectCode,
    bl.PartNum AS PartNum, 
    SUM(pm.Quantity * bl.TotalQty) AS BOMItemCount, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN blh.ParentPartNum = bl.PartNum 
            THEN pm.Quantity * bl.TotalQty 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS NextBOMItemCount,
    bl.mp AS mp, 
    p.complete AS complete, 
    bl.RMInd AS RMInd, 
    bl.M_PartNum AS M_PartNum
FROM 
    projectmachine AS pm 
    INNER JOIN projectbomlist AS bl 
        ON  pm.MachineListID = bl.MachineListID 
        AND pm.ProjectCode = bl.ProjectCode
    INNER JOIN join projects AS p 
        ON  pm.ProjectCode = p.ProjectCode 
        AND p.AfterProjectHeirarchyInd = 'Y'
    INNER JOIN projectbomlistheirarchy blh
        ON  bl.ProjectCode = blh.ProjectCode 
WHERE 
    pm.ProjectCode = 'AB212323'
GROUP BY 
    pm.ProjectCode, 
    bl.PartNum,
    bl.mp,
    p.complete,
    bl.RMInd, 
    bl.M_PartNum
ORDER BY 
    pm.ProjectCode, 
    bl.PartNum
```